# IOException: The process cannot access the file 'file path' because it is being used by another process in Console Application in C#

Tags: c#, ioexception, streamwriter, error-log

I am running Console_Application-A in which I am calling another Console_Application-B (in which I am creating log file for Error/Exception).

But when I am running Console_Application-B individually its working properly but when I am running Console_Application-A at that time I am getting an Exception when Application need to write an Error in log file.(Error.txt).

> IOException: The process cannot access the file 'Error.txt' because it
>   is being used by another process

please guide me in this issue.

Code for Writing Error log

```
public static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
{
 FileStream stream = null;
 try
 {
 stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
 }
 catch (IOException)
 {
  return true;
 }
 finally
 {
  if (stream != null)
  stream.Close();
  }
  return false;
 }
```

---

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    string filePath =Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\Error.txt";

FileInfo FInfo = new FileInfo(filePath);
var FileState = IsFileLocked(FInfo);

while (FileState){
FileState = IsFileLocked(FInfo);
}
if (!FileState){
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
{
 writer.WriteLine("Message :" + e.Message + "<br/>" + Environment.NewLine + "StackTrace :" + e.StackTrace +"" + Environment.NewLine + "Date :" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
 writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine);
writer.Dispose();
}
}
}
```

Comment: Both applications access the same file at the same time?

Comment: add your code for writing into log file.

Comment: No Both applications are using different files

Comment: Error msg is very clear  you are trying to access a file and is not accessible because used by another process. You have not pasted code , but I am guessing  implements IDisposable and wrap code inside a using statement will work. Hope that will helps

Comment: I added Code also to write into a log file please check it and help me out !

Answer (score 0):

There is no need first to check if the file is locked and then access it, as between the check and the access some other process may still get a lock on the file.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class DirAppend
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("log.txt"))
        {
            Log("Test1", w);
            Log("Test2", w);
        }

        using (StreamReader r = File.OpenText("log.txt"))
        {
            DumpLog(r);
        }
    }

    public static void Log(string logMessage, TextWriter w)
    {
        w.Write("\r\nLog Entry : ");
        w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
            DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
        w.WriteLine("  :");
        w.WriteLine("  :{0}", logMessage);
        w.WriteLine ("-------------------------------");
    }

    public static void DumpLog(StreamReader r)
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
    }
}
```

Source - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3zc0w663(v=vs.110).aspx